# Can i get models field type from a model queryset in Django?

Tags: django, django-models

Can i get model field type from a model queryset in Django?

For example:
`a` is `b` model's queryset and the `b` model has following fields:

- f:charfield
- g:foreignkey
- h:manytomany

Is there any way to get field `g`'s type from queryset `a`? 
thx.

Comment: Why would you need the field type? Wouldn't it be easier to check the results and determine the field type from the result.

Answer (score 39):

I have the answer:

```
a.model._meta.get_field('g').get_internal_type()
```

Comment: I am new to python, but thought the leading underscore meant 'do not use'.

Comment: @TimP usually the leading underscore does mean "do not use." However, I gather from reading around SO that the `_meta` object has been growingly canonical in Django over the last few versions, and it is used extensively internally in Django. I say go ahead and use it, but make sure to run your tests (you're writing unit tests, right?) when upgrading Django versions. But in general, you're right, avoid using _single_leading_underscore symbols from third-party libraries in Python.

Answer (score 3):

```
fields = [f.attname for f in Experience._meta.fields]
file_fields = []
print("FILE FIELDS : ", fields)
for field in fields:
    get_type = Experience._meta.get_field(field)
    print("GET TYPE :", get_type)
    field_type = get_type.__class__.__name__
    print(field, "FILE TYPE : ", field_type)
    if field_type == "FileField":
        file_fields.append(field)
```

This code can get the field types of django models.

Comment: This works great!